# eliminating text which include new lines

Tags: perl

Working with perl and reading a file line by line, I need to eliminate all text included between two specific words (let's say "dog" and "cat"), but I don't know how to do that when there are various lines bewtween both words. Iim tryng to use the "s" modifier, which means the dot (.) can be interpreted as a new line, but it doesn't work:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
my $filename = shift;
open F, $filename or die "Usa: $0 FILENAME\n";
while(<F>) {
s/dog.*?cat//s;
print;
}
close F;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are reading in your file line by line, then substituting. If you want the whole text at once, set the input record separator to undef with

```
local $/;
```

Then, when you do <F>, you get the whole file content, and the substitution should work.

Comment: Note that you should do this in a separate block, so that `$/` reverts to its previous value after reading the file.

Comment: Since the OP used shift, I suppose this code is embedded in a sub, therefore, it should revert after exiting the sub.

Comment: @blueygh2 You can also use `shift` to get command line arguments, so that's a poor assumption.

Answer (score 1):

```
while (<F>) {
  my $n = s/dog.*//s .. s/.*?cat//;
  $n ||= 0;
  print if $n <= 1 or $n =~ /E/;
}
```

Comment: I'd probably make it `print if !$n || $n == 1 || $n =~ /E/;` so that his good use of [warnings](http://perldoc.perl.org/warnings.html) doesn't throw a bunch of messages.  Also it's important to note that this will re-cycle through if it sees another dog after the cat.  That might be desired behavior, but could also lead to a bug if the OP isn't expecting it.

Comment: Two more bugs.  1)  You need the `s` modifier on the first test so that the new line will be stripped.  2) Much harder is this doesn't work if dog and cat are on the same line because you strip everything after dog or before cat.

Comment: @ mpapec Finally, for some reason I'm unable to @ message you in comments.  If I remove the space at the beginning there, it simply strips the @mpapec.  Would you happen to know why that is?

Comment: @Miller There's no need for the `@`, [authors are automatically notified about all comments on their own posts](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work).

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot TY.  I read that in detail.  The wizardry where it was automatically removing the @ if it was redundant or not recognizing tab completion was confusing me.

Comment: @Miller yes there are cases when it doesn't behave like plain `s///` and OP should provide some input example.

Answer (score 0):

The answer above is correct. I've just dealt with this issue myself. You can try:

```
use strict;
my $filename = shift;
open F, $filename or die "Usa: $0 FILENAME\n";
my $buffer;
{ 
   local $/;
   $buffer = <F>;
   $buffer =~ s/dog.*?cat//s;
}
print $buffer;
```

Note that this might have side effects you do not want. Consider the input:

```
dog foo dog bar cat
```

Do you want the 'foo' included in what is not printed? By default, regular expressions are greedy and will remove the 'foo'...which may or may not be what you want.

The CPAN module [Regexp::Common::balanced](http://search.cpan.org/~abigail/Regexp-Common-2013031301/lib/Regexp/Common/balanced.pm) can help you iron out the correct way you wish to handle these kinds of edge cases.

Answer (score 0):

Slurping your file by localizing $/ is going to be your easiest solution.  However, if you want to do line by line processing, then you just need to keep track of a $state variable

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

my $filename = shift;
#open my $fh, '<', $filename;

my $state = 0;

while(<DATA>) {
    if ($state == 0 && s/(.*?)dog//) {
        print $1;
        $state = 1;
    }

    if ($state == 1 && s/.*?cat//) {
        $state = 2;
# If you want to handle more than one dog/cat pair, use below code
#       $state = 0;
#       redo;
    }

    if ($state != 1) {
        print;
    }
}

#close $fh;

__DATA__
1 hello world
2 more lines
3 this cat is ignored
4 and yet more
5 this has <dog ... yep, it really does
6 stuff to delete
7 this has cat>, cuz cats rock
8 Filler line
9 more <dogs are ignored.
10 more cat>s
11 more filler
12 yet more filler
13 More <dogs and cat>s and stuff
14 more filler
15 more filler
16 more <dogs and cat>s and <dogs and cat>s, see.
17 ending stuff
```

Outputs

```
1 hello world
2 more lines
3 this cat is ignored
4 and yet more
5 this has <>, cuz cats rock
8 Filler line
9 more <dogs are ignored.
10 more cat>s
11 more filler
12 yet more filler
13 More <dogs and cat>s and stuff
14 more filler
15 more filler
16 more <dogs and cat>s and <dogs and cat>s, see.
17 ending stuff
```

If you uncomment those two lines so that more than 1 dog/cat pair are filtered, then you get the following:

```
1 hello world
2 more lines
3 this cat is ignored
4 and yet more
5 this has <>, cuz cats rock
8 Filler line
9 more <>s
11 more filler
12 yet more filler
13 More <>s and stuff
14 more filler
15 more filler
16 more <>s and <>s, see.
17 ending stuff
```